# Making my ellipse a button to show some data on the same window?

Tags: java, processing

Hello im trying to make my ellipse shape a button so that when i double click it, it should show a snap-view of the data. I've created some code but its not 100% functional and would be nice if someone can help me.

Code:

```java
boolean drawText = false;
void setup(){
  size(800,600);
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(245, 27, 27, 151);
  ellipse(110,110,120,120);
  if(dist(mouseX,mouseY,110,110)<60){
    cursor(HAND);
  } else {
    cursor(ARROW);
  }
  if (drawText) {
    fill(#FFFF00);
    text("Hi!", 110, 110);
  }
}
void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT && dist(mouseX,mouseY,110,110)<60) {
    drawText = true;
  } else if (mouseButton == LEFT && dist(mouseX,mouseY,110,110)<60){
   drawText = false; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember your geometry class? You have to math your way out of this by finding if the coordinates of the mouse at the moment of the click are in the circle.

Comment: Hello @laancelot i've managed to make the button clickable with text showing except, when the button is clicked the second time i dont want it it to show the text. Because right now i can only click it once and i dont want that to happen.

Comment: Congrats for improving on your code! I don't have a lot of context, but are you willing to use classes (you could make a "button" class to keep things clean, and I can help with that).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand your question the right way, but judging from it and your comment under it, I understand, that you want the text to be shown, when the button is clicked once and hidden when the button is clicked again. If so, this code should work for you:

```
boolean drawText = false;
void setup(){
  size(800,600);
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(245, 27, 27, 151);
  ellipse(110,110,120,120);
  if(dist(mouseX,mouseY,110,110)<60){
    cursor(HAND);
  } else {
    cursor(ARROW);
  }
  if (drawText) {
    fill(#FFFF00);
    text("Hi!", 110, 110);
  }
}
void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseButton == LEFT && dist(mouseX,mouseY,110,110)<60) {
    drawText = !drawText;
  }
}
```

So, when the button is clicked now, drawText is changed to its opposite: If it was `true` before, then it is set to `false` and the other way round. That way, clicking the button makes the text visible and clicking it again makes the text invisible again.

## Edit: Another way of understanding your question

Another way of understanding your question is that you want the text to be shown only after a double-click on the button. In that case, you can make use of the `evt.getCount()` function inside `mousePressed`. It resturns 1 after a single click, 2 after a double click and so on. Here is some code to make that work:

```
boolean drawText = false;
void setup(){
  size(800,600);
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(245, 27, 27, 151);
  ellipse(110,110,120,120);
  if(dist(mouseX,mouseY,110,110)<60){
    cursor(HAND);
  } else {
    cursor(ARROW);
  }
  if (drawText) {
    fill(#FFFF00);
    text("Hi!", 110, 110);
  }
}
void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
  if (evt.getCount() == 2) {  // detect double click
    if (mouseButton == LEFT && dist(mouseX,mouseY,110,110)<60) {
      drawText = !drawText;
    }
  }
}
```